# find duplicates in Ruby array of arrays, sum their values, then combine them

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a pipe delimited text file that i am looping through that looks like so:

```
123|ADAM JOHNSON|AAUA|||||||||||1||||
123||AAUA||||||||8675|90.0|90.0||||||||
444|STEVE SMITH|AAUA|||||||||||1|||||
444||AAUA||||||||2364|50.0|50.0|||||||
444||AAUA||||||||8453|50.0|50.0||||
567|ALLEN JONES|AAUA|||||||||||1||||||
567||AAUA||||||||6578|75.0|75.0||||||
567||AAUA||||||||1234|10.0|10.0||||
567||AAUA||||||||1234|15.0|15.0|||||
```

What I start with is grab the first, tenth and eleventh indexes of these rows and put them into an array of arrays like so:

```
CSV.foreach('data.txt', { :col_sep => '|' }) do |row|
  if row[1].nil?
    @group_array << [row[0], [row[10], row[11]]]
  end
end
```

So I get something like:

```
[["123", ["8675", "90.0"]]
------------------
["444", ["2364", "50.0"]]
["444", ["8453", "50.0"]]
------------------
["567", ["6578", "75.0"]]
["567", ["1234", "10.0"]]
["567", ["1234", "15.0"]]]
```

What I am struggling with is looping through the arrays, finding groupings with the same first index (the 3 integer ids), looping through that then finding any duplicates in the second array with the same 4 integer id, then adding the third index floats then spitting out a final array with the duplicates removed and their values summed.

Expected output should look like:

```
[["0006310001", ["789663473", "90.0"]],
["0006410001", ["297103188", "50.0"]],
["0006410001", ["757854164", "50.0"]],
["0006610001", ["557493572", "75.0"]],
["0006610001", ["981894386", "25.0"]]]
```

Comment: Yes, clarification is needed, but you should have done that before posting the question.

Comment: Also, post what ur expected output looks like.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it's no excuse but this has been a work in progress and i was severely spinning my wheels. @SteveTurczyn has already provided an answer that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your data item looks like `[["123", ["8675", "90.0"]]]` based on how it's created... more likely it looks like `["123", ["8675", "90.0"]]`

In which case, this should do what you want...

```
group_array = @group_array.sort
result = []
save_3 = nil
save_4 = nil
total = 0.0
group_array.each do |group|
  if group[0] != save_3 || group[1][0] != save_4
    result << [save_3, [save_4, total.to_s]] if save_3
    total = 0.0
    save_3 = group[0]
    save_4 = group[1][0]
  end
  total += group[1][1].to_f
end
result << [save_3, [save_4, total.to_s]] if save_3
```

Comment: You are correct that I would not have an array of arrays within an array, i will change my above post. That was the case when I was throwing @group_array into a master array while individually looping through the csv file. i think going the batch route like above could be better.

Comment: Well it could be done while you're doing the initial build.  Are you sure the CSV is sorted?  You won't have (for example) `["567", ["1234", "15.0"]], ["567", ["6578", "75.0"]],["567", ["1234", "10.0"]]` We can insert if they''re out of order but it'll run faster if they're in order.

Comment: The CSV is not initially sorted, no. I will have the example you just gave where the first index of the second array will be out of order, they could be anywhere within the group. Also is this process able to scale well? Say i have a csv with thousands of rows..

Comment: Ok, I've posted another answer that will work with unordered data and will have better scaleability.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something that should scale a bit better...

```
group_hash = Hash.new(0.0)
CSV.foreach('data.txt', { :col_sep => '|' }) do |row|
  if row[1].nil?
    group_hash[ [row[0], row[10]] ] += row[11].to_f
  end
end
# produces a hash with key [a, b] value sum_of_c
# if you need an array of [a, [b,c]] then next step is...
@group_array = group_hash.to_a.map{|entry| [entry[0][0], [entry[0][1], entry[1]]]}
```